# Conda: what happens when you activate an environment?

Tags: path, conda

How does running `source activate <env-name>` update the $PATH variable? I've been looking in the `CONDA-INSTALLATION/bin/activate` script and do not understand how conda updates my $PATH variable to include the bin directory for the recently activated environment. No where can I find the code that conda uses to prepend my $PATH variable.

Comment: What version of conda are you using? The behavior has changed between conda < 4.4 and conda >=4.4

Comment: Hi, I'm running version 4.4.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a conda developer, and I'm not a Bash expert. The following explanation is based on me tracing through the code, and I hope I got it all right. Also, all of the links below are permalinks to the master commit at the time of writing this answer ([`7cb5f66`](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5)). Behavior/lines may change in future commits. Beware: Deep rabbit hole ahead!

Note that this explanation is for the command `source activate env-name`, but in conda>=4.4, the recommended way to activate an environment is `conda activate env-name`. I think if one uses `conda activate env-name`, you should pick up the explanation around the part where we get into the `cli.main` function.

For conda >=4.4,<4.5, looking at `CONDA_INST_DIR/bin/activate`, we find on the second to last and last lines ([GitHub link](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/shell/bin/activate#L64)):

```
. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
_conda_activate "$@"
```

The first line sources the script `conda.sh` in the `$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d` directory, and that script defins the `_conda_activate` bash function, to which we pass the arguments `$@` which is basically all of the arguments that we passed to the `activate` script.

Taking the next step down the rabbit hole, we look at `$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` and find ([GitHub link](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/shell/etc/profile.d/conda.sh#L55)):

```
_conda_activate() {
# Some code removed...
    local ask_conda
    ask_conda="$(PS1="$PS1" $_CONDA_EXE shell.posix activate "$@")" || return $?
    eval "$ask_conda"

    _conda_hashr
}
```

The key is that line `ask_conda=...`, and particularly `$_CONDA_EXE shell.posix activate "$@"`. Here, we are running the conda executable with the arguments `shell.posix`, `activate`, and then the rest of the arguments that got passed to this function (i.e., the environment name that we want to activate).

Another step into the rabbit hole... From here, the conda executable calls the [`cli.main` function](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/cli/main.py#L109) and since the first argument starts with `shell.`, it imports the `main` function from `conda.activate`. This function creates an instance of the `Activator` class (defined in the same file) and [runs the `execute` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L573).

The `execute` method processes the arguments and [stores the passed environment name into an instance variable](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L193), then decides that the [`activate` command has been passed](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L195), so it [runs the `activate` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L157).

Another step into the rabbit hole... The `activate` method calls the [`build_activate` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L222), which calls [another function](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/base/context.py#L931) to process the environment name to find the environment prefix (i.e., which folder the environment is in). Finally, the [`build_activate` method adds the `prefix` to the `PATH`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L244) via the [`_add_prefix_to_path` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L407). Finally, the `build_activate` method [returns a dictionary](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L283) of commands that need to be run to "activate" the environment.

And another step deeper... The dictionary returned from the `build_activate` method gets processed into shell commands by the [`_yield_commands` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L197), which are passed into the `_finalize` method. The `activate` method returns the value from running [the `_finalize` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L129) which returns the name of a temp file. The temp file has the commands required to set all of the appropriate environment variables.

Now, stepping back out, in the `activate.main` function, the return value of the `execute` method (i.e., the name of the temp file) is [printed to stdout](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L573). This temp file name gets stored in the Bash variable `ask_conda` back in the `_conda_activate` Bash function, and finally, the temp file is executed by the `eval` Bash function.

Phew! I hope I got everything right. As I said, I'm not a conda developer, and far from a Bash expert, so please excuse any explanation shortcuts I took that aren't 100% correct. Just leave a comment, I'll be happy to fix it!

I should also note that the recommended method to activate environments in conda >=4.4 is `conda activate env-name`, which is one of the reasons this is so convoluted - the activation is mostly handled in Python now, whereas (I think) previously it was more-or-less handled directly in Bash/CMD.