# activating conda env vs calling python interpreter from conda env

Tags: environment-variables, anaconda, conda

What *exactly* is the difference between these two operations?

`source activate python3_env && python my_script.py`
and
`~/anaconda3/envs/python3_env/bin/python my_script.py` ?

It appears that activating the environment adds some variables to $PATH, but the second method seems to access all the modules installed in `python3_env`.  Is there anything else going on under the hood?

Comment: There is nothing else going under the hood. Take a look at `~/anaconda3/envs/python3_env/bin/python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

Comment: @NehalJWani That is not correct. See my answer below.

Comment: @anon01 The command for recent versions of conda (>=4.4) is `conda activate env_name`, not `source activate env_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, activating the environment adds some directories to the `PATH` environment variable. In particular, this will allow any binaries or scripts installed in the environment to be run first, instead of the ones in the base environment. For instance, if you have installed IPython into your environment, activating the environment allows you to write

```
ipython
```

to start IPython in the environment, rather than

```
/path/to/env/bin/ipython
```

In addition, environments may have scripts that add or edit other environment variables that are executed when the environment is activated (see the [conda docs](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux)). These scripts can make arbitrary changes to the shell environment, including even changing the `PYTHONPATH` to change where packages are loaded from.

Finally, I wrote a very detailed answer of what exactly is happening in the code over there: [Conda: what happens when you activate an environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585040/conda-what-happens-when-you-activate-an-environment) That may or may not still be up-to-date though. The relevant part of the answer is:

> ...the [`build_activate` method adds the `prefix` to the `PATH`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L244) via the [`_add_prefix_to_path` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L407). Finally, the `build_activate` method [returns a dictionary](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L283) of commands that need to be run to "activate" the environment.
>
> And another step deeper... The dictionary returned from the `build_activate` method gets processed into shell commands by the [`_yield_commands` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L197), which are passed into the `_finalize` method. The `activate` method returns the value from running [the `_finalize` method](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L129) which returns the name of a temp file. The temp file has the commands required to set all of the appropriate environment variables.
>
> Now, stepping back out, in the `activate.main` function, the return value of the `execute` method (i.e., the name of the temp file) is [printed to stdout](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7cb5f66dd46727ce8f16b969e084555e6221cfc5/conda/activate.py#L573). This temp file name gets stored in the Bash variable `ask_conda` back in the `_conda_activate` Bash function, and finally, the temp file is executed by the `eval` Bash function.

So you can see, depending on the environment, running `conda activate python3_env && python my_script.py` and `~/anaconda3/envs/python3_env/bin/python my_script.py` may give very different results.

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I wanted.  Clear and thorough.